# Not able to delete video file from gallery using AngularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, video, ionic-framework

I am recording a video using cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin and that video is visible in gallery which i don't want to be. I tried to delete the video after copying that file to my project directory. I am able to delete the file from the file path but video is still visible in gallery (which is not playing).

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The gallery is using Android's media database to display the list of media. Deleting the file will not be reflected in the database until it scans the filesystem again. That is for example done after rebooting.

I know the native android fix for this. After delete the video update the gallery by using following method

```
public void UpdateGallery(String filePath) {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))));
}
```

you probably need to to write an own plugin to above method or modify the existing plugin code to update the galary.

Comment: is there any other option to hide video from gallery?

Comment: As of my knowledge there is no other option. Either you have to reboot the phone or u have to scan the file system.

Comment: Please post if you got the answer for this

Comment: Hi. Where to put this method? In FileUtils.java of File plugin?

Comment: yes you can put it there and make a call to the method, or you can write a seperate plugin and call whenever you want to scan the file system